# tomcat 6: cannot stop autodeploy

Tags: eclipse, deployment, tomcat6

I want to stop tomcat's auto-deployment for which I have checked the `Never publish automatically` in Eclipse Galileo's Servers view. But I am not able it keeps auto-publishing every 10 seconds. I also changed the `autoDeploy` property in `server.xml` from `true` to `false` but somehow its still auto-deploying.

Could someone help me turn the auto-deployment off? I already have the `Build Automatically` unchecked in the `Project` tab of Eclipse.

I am getting an additional `ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]..` on the console that did not use to be there with the `DEBUG` level logging. What I used to see on the console was `DEBUG[main]..` but now what I see is `DEBUG[ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]]..`. I've made no changes in my application except that I was using a 32 bit OS (Windows XP) earlier and now I am using 64 bit (Windows 7).

**EDIT**: I think its not the auto-deployment but auto context reloading by `ContainerBackgroundProcessor` thread as I still need to publish to make the changes in my application.

Thanks.

Comment: odd. are you sure you saved the server configuration in eclipse?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I've changed the tomcat6 32 bit to tomcat6 64 bit but still no help.